Error Exporting Enum from NPM Workspace in Angular-Nest Project
I'm working on an Angular-Nest project using a monorepo structure with multiple workspaces. I am trying to export an enum from the types workspace and use it in the server workspace, but I'm encountering an error.
Here is the structure of my project:
my-monorepo/
├── client/
├── server/
│   ├── dist/
│   ├── src/
│   │   ├── auth/
│   │   ├── booking/
│   │   ├── common/
│   │   ├── listing/
│   │   ├── user/
│   │   ├── app.module.ts
│   │   ├── config.schema.ts
│   │   ├── main.ts
│   │   └── transform.interceptor.ts
│   ├── test/
│   ├── .eslint.rc.js
│   ├── .gitignore
│   ├── .prettierrc
│   ├── gcpServiceAccountKey.json
│   ├── nest-cli.json
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── tsconfig.build.json
│   ├── tsconfig.json
├── types/
│   ├── src/
│   │   ├── listing/
│   │   │   ├── index.ts
│   │   │   ├── listing.interface.ts
│   │   │   ├── listing-image.interface.ts
│   │   ├── booking.interface.ts
│   │   ├── index.ts
│   │   ├── user.interface.ts
│   ├── package.json

In the types workspace, I have defined an enum in src/listing/index.ts:
// types/src/listing/index.ts
export enum ListingImageCategory {
  EXTERIOR = 'exterior',
  BEDROOM = 'bedroom',
  BATHROOM = 'bathroom',
  COMMON_AREA = 'common_area',
}

The package.json of the types workspace looks like this:
{
  "name": "@my-org/types",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "src/index.ts",
  "type": "module"
}

In the server workspace, I am trying to import the enum like this:
// server/src/listing/dto/add-listing-image.dto.ts
import {
  IsEnum,
  IsOptional,
  IsString,
  MaxLength,
  MinLength,
} from 'class-validator';
import { ListingImageCategory } from '../entities/listing-image.entity';

export class AddListingImageDto {
  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  @MinLength(4)
  @MaxLength(50)
  label?: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsEnum(ListingImageCategory)
  category: ListingImageCategory;
}

But I am getting the following error:
export * from './user.interface'
^^^^^^

invalid export

I've ensured that both workspaces are installed and linked correctly. Can someone help me figure out what might be going wrong?
Here is a link to my GitHub repository: https://github.com/Soumajit2004/angular-nest-airbnb-clone/
Thanks in advance!
everything is explained in question
